# change Codeigniter controller class name using filename

Tags: php, codeigniter

i need to change Ci controller class name automatically when i change it's filename.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access 
allowed');
class $filename extends CI_Controller {
}
```

how can i do this?

Comment: use a clever IDE that supports this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this

```
$filename = ucfirst(preg_replace("/[^a-z!]/",'',strtolower(pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_FILENAME))));

class {$filename} extends CI_Controller {}
```

The pathinfo(**FILE**, PATHINFO_FILENAME) part get the current filename.

The {} makes sure the $filename is first converted to its value and then a new class can be created with that name.

The ucfirst(strtolower()) is so that you get a capital for the first letter.

I would be very carefull with this, since strange characters can break this very easy. Therefor I added the preg_replace